# How to make Script-Migration in EFCore to add "USE" statement at the start?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have an older system, where I am trying to fit the new technology, i.e. *EF Core* (yes, only version 3.1.32 is supported by *.NET Framework* - it's still better than nothing).

Instead of generating the SQL scripts manually, I can now use `Script-Migration` command. But I need it to spit out `USE [database-name] / GO` lines in the very beginning of the script. Is there a way to it, save for creating some post-build action or a custom task?

Comment: Why do you need to put a `USE` at the start of the script? Why not have the process connect to the correct database in the first place?

Comment: In .NET Framework it's probably better to use EF 6.x than EF Core 3. EF Core 3 lacked many of the EF 6.x features that were added in later versions without offering significant benefits. EF Core 3 was the first version that offered most of EF 6's basic features

Comment: Also, `GO` is not a T-SQL keyword. It's an extension keyword that's implemented by SSMS, `sqlcmd` and a couple of other tools to act as a batch separator, but it's a syntax error if it ever makes its way to SQL Server itself.

Comment: I need `USE` because the script is used somewhere deep in the system without connecting to the correct database. I can't currently change that.

I know `GO` is not a SQL keyword, but it is used by SSMS and many other tools as statement separator.

Comment: I believe there is a brighter future for _.NET Core_ than for _.NET Framework_. So to get closer to this future I can sacrifice a few features, but not add yet another block when we start converting to _.NET Core_.

Comment: @Mike a statement separator is not the same as a batch separator. `;` is a statement separator and is defined as such in T-SQL syntax, whereas `GO` is a batch separator and is not defined in T-SQL syntax. In `DECLARE @Foo INT`, for example, `@Foo` will continue to exist past statement separators but it goes "poof" out of existence as soon as you reach a batch separator.

Comment: For what I know, you can't use a statement separator in certain places, like after creating a table or after `USE`. But regardless, I take it as there is no integrated way for me to add something to the generated script.